# How to add a dynamic listview layout inside a parent list view?

Tags: android, android-layout, android-listview

I am new to android in my android layout i got listview inside a listview both the listviews should be repeat dynamically.here i have to acheive the curriculum fragment layout.In curriculum CREATION:making your idea center title is the parent list view and the bellow CREATION: audio and workbook is the sub listview.how can i achieve it.

[image]

Comment: Can you demonstrate a bit with some drawing?

Comment: use `Expandable list view` instead..

Comment: what do you want nested listview ?

Comment: @shahzeb i have added the layout screen could you please check it once.

Comment: please point out the exact layout. I still couldn't get what you want

Comment: i have to achieve the curriculum fragment layout view

Comment: @Mohit can you please give me  the reference example for expandable list view

Comment: @USKMobility yes i want a nested listview.can you please give me the reference

Comment: [this](http://androidexample.com/Custom_Expandable_ListView_Tutorial_-_Android_Example/index.php?view=article_discription&aid=107&aaid=129),[this](http://javapapers.com/android/android-expandable-listview/),[this](http://www.androidhive.info/2013/07/android-expandable-list-view-tutorial/)